# How can i use react-beautiful-dnd inside of Ant Desing List?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, antd

I using ant Desing list. I want drag and sort them with react-beautiful-dnd. But while i trying drag, its not dragging any and its giving me that 2 error :

```
Invariant failed: Cannot collect without a droppable ref
```

&&

```
Invariant failed: Cannot stop drag when no active drag
```

How can i solve it ? My codes :

```
const someData = [
  {
    id: "gary",
    sort: 1,
    name: "Gary Goodspeed",
    thumb: "/images/gary.png"
  },
  {
    id: "cato",
    sort: 0,
    name: "Little Cato",
    thumb: "/images/cato.png"
  },

  {
    id: "kvn",
    sort: 2,
    name: "KVN",
    thumb: "/images/kvn.png"
  },
  {
    id: "mooncake",
    sort: 3,
    name: "Mooncake",
    thumb: "/images/mooncake.png"
  },
  {
    id: "quinn",
    sort: 4,
    name: "Quinn Ergon",
    thumb: "/images/quinn.png"
  }
];
export default function App() {
  function handleOnDragEnd(result) {
    if (!result.destination) return;

    const items = Array.from(someData);
    const [reorderedItem] = items.splice(result.source.index, 1);
    items.splice(result.destination.index, 0, reorderedItem);
    const Obj = [];

    console.log("obj", Obj);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleOnDragEnd}>
        <Droppable droppableId="DropId">
          {(provided) => (
            <List
              header={
                <div className="w-full m-0 p-0  ">
                  <p>Header</p>
                </div>
              }
              bordered
              rowKey="Id"
              dataSource={someData && someData}
              size="small"
              renderItem={(item, index) => (
                <Draggable draggableId="DropId" index={index}>
                  {(provided) => (
                    <div
                      ref={provided.innerRef}
                      {...provided.draggableProps}
                      {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                    >
                      <List.Item>
                        <span
                          ref={provided.innerRef}
                          {...provided.draggableProps}
                          {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                        >
                          {item.name}
                        </span>

                        {provided.placeholder}
                      </List.Item>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </Draggable>
              )}
            ></List>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </DragDropContext>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried write Draggable outside of List.Item  but its same result with div.
Thanks for all answers!
For more details : My sandbox : [codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-saha-q0lfs](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-saha-q0lfs)

Comment: can you add a codesandbox with a small example ?

Comment: @Shyam i didnt use codesandbox any but i will try add now for you brother.

Comment: do you want to re-arrange the items within the same list or you want to transfer the items from one list to another ?

Comment: @Shyam I want to re-arrange items for sorting. I wont transfer item one list to another.

Comment: @Shyam https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-saha-q0lfs my sandbox kinda like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are Dragging and Dropping in the same list, you need to wrap your list with the `<div>` and pass the props provided from the Droppable component .

```
 <Droppable droppableId="DropId">
    {(provided) => (
       <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps}>
          <List ... />
          {provided.placeholder}
       </div>
    )}
</Droppable>
```

Also it is just enough to pass the draggable props to the `<div>` wrapped over the `<List.item>` . We can remove the `<span>` wrapped over the `{item.name}`.

[Drag Drop Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-benz-xex7i?file=/src/App.js)